# Total.js Custom System View

Tags: javascript, node.js, total.js

I would like to use controller.view500(err) and display a custom system view.

How to display a custom system view 500, 400 ?

https://docs.totaljs.com/latest/en.html#api~FrameworkController~controller.view

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function view500 doesn't actually render any view. It's just an alias for throw500.

If you want to render a view you can define a custom route like this:

```
F.route('#500', function(){
    // You need to create the view '500.html' file yourself in views folder
    this.view('500');
});
```

Then whenever you use `controller.view500();` the above route will handle it.
The error you pass to `view500` should be available in the route controller as `controller.exception`